# Do you convert real images (used in splash) into nine-patch?

Tags: android, screen-resolution, nine-patch

As the title says, when you deal with real images which appear in splash screens or on background or in Alert popups, do you convert them to nine-patch or you simply resize them into several images (800x480, 960x540 , 720x1280, etc.)?

I am not converting them to nine-patch but resize to most-used formats and I am wondering if I am making a mistake in so doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that it definitely depends on how you want your image to behave on different screen sizes.

If you want to specify that some areas of the image can be stretched and some others cannot, then 9-patch seems relevant.

On the other hand, if your image should not be transformed/stretched then you'd better give as many image sizes as required to cover a majority of screens.

Comment: well it is suppose to stretch but as a whole. like when I use it in splash where it has to `fill_parent` and be full screen. naturally, it will stretch with each screen. do you suggest nine-patch in such situations or nine-patch should be used when **only some part of the image have to stretch**?

Comment: In that case I would provide several images. 9-patch files are only suitable when an area of the image can be safely stretched independently of the rest of the image (such as a blank area near the border)